# Is the use of "can" in descriptive statements simply a matter of preference?

Tags: tenses

If I were describing a motorcycle to a potential buyer, I would have to describe its specs. The usual selling points for adrenaline junkies are top speed and 0-60 MPH acceleration (or 0-100 for track bikes).

If I say, "This bike accelerates from 0 to 60 MPH in 3.2 seconds." it's somewhat obvious that one could accelerate *slower* than that if they chose to. Does that mean I am only relying on the context of the statement to convey, "This bike *can accelerate* from 0 to 60 MPH in 3.2 seconds."?

When describing general abilities, when do you use "can"?

What are the different tense names for saying "X can do W, Y, and Z." verses "X does W, Y, and Z." and when do we prefer one over the other?

Comment: Define "*simply a matter of preference*", and describe the alternative(s).

Comment: @Drew Your preference might be brevity or emphasis. The alternative to using "can", as you'll see in the examples in the question, is just to state it in simple present tense. For describing inanimate objects, like cars, software, etc., there really isn't a distinction in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, bothering to say what goes without saying is a matter of preference.  You could just not say it.

That doesn't mean it always goes without saying.  I **can** write an answer that you would find helpful, but will I?

`Can` vs. `does` isn't simply a matter of tense.  `Can` is about possibilities.  `Does`  is about certainties.

Answer (score 1):

The criterion for using "does" over "can do" is contextual, yes. But the context is more "is this the prime or sole characteristic of interest?" (E.g. the "maximums" in the case of performance machines.)